# Use azure appsettings to read connection string for EventHubTrigger in azure webjob

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-webjobs, azure-eventhub

I am writing a azure webjob using .Net core 3.1 and reading the events from eventhub. I have been able to get this working locally where I read all settings from local appsettings.json and appsettings.dev.json.

`public async Task ProcessEvent([EventHubTrigger("%EventHubName%", Connection = "EventHubConfigConnectionString", ConsumerGroup = "%ConsumerGroupName%")] EventData eventData)`

However, I now tried using the azure appservice appsettings to store the connection string where the app settings are exposed as environment variables, which I am adding to the configuration as:

`Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();`

But I still get the error:

`System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Primitives.Guard.ArgumentNotNullOrWhiteSpace(String argumentName, String value)`

I verified that the variable names are the same.
I read online and looks like the connection string to the EventHubTrigger has to be present in appsettings file and not in environment variable?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You should have an entry in your `appSettings.json` file, I would say under the `connectionStrings` section like below:

```
{
  "AppInsights_InstrumentationKey": "",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "EventHubConfigConnectionString": ""
  }
}
```

I think in the Azure portal, for your app service, you can set a new connection string with the name `EventHubConfigConnectionString` which will override the one that is in your appSettings.json file:

[image: Connection strings section under configuration blade of App service]

Then in your `Program.cs` have the following maybe:

```
Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                    .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", optional: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                    .Build();
```

Hope this helps.